# Difference between adb uninstall and adb uninstall --user 0

Tags: android, apk, adb

I recently discovered that I can remove the factory version of chrome from a device with:

```sh
adb uninstall --user 0 com.android.chrome
```

However, after the app is uninstalled, I can no longer reinstall chrome with:

```sh
adb install-multiple chrome-split-apk-dir
```

The command does not fail, however chrome is not present on the device after the install completes:

```sh
$ pm list packages | grep chrome
1
```

However I can install chrome by using the `--user 0` option again:

```sh
adb install-multiple --user 0 chrome-split-apk-dir
```

My question(s):

- Why can I uninstall factory chrome version `--user 0`? I thought that if you don't include the user, the app will be uninstalled from all users by default, including `--user 0`, so the behaviour shouldn't be different.
- Why can I now only reinstall chrome by using `--user 0` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--user specifies the user to run as, not the user its uninstalled from.  0 is root in Linux.  You're telling it to run the uninstall command as root, which obviously has heightened privileges and can do it.  A normal user doesn't and can't.  The same applies for install.

Comment: That makes sense. But why can the chrome only be reinstalled with root after uninstalling with root?

Comment: I found out that if I install without root user, and then run this command: `cmd package install-existing com.android.chrome`, the app reappears.

Comment: There was a slight difference in the dumpsys of the chrome package before/after running the above command. Before: `User 0: ceDataInode=0 installed=false hidden=false suspended=false stopped=true notLaunched=true enabled=0 instant=false virtual=false`, and after: `User 0: ceDataInode=9797 installed=true hidden=false suspended=false stopped=false notLaunched=false enabled=0 instant=false virtual=false`